# How to maintain a pointer for a list item [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to enable keyboard control (arrow up/down)

I've my jquery codes as

```
if($('.yumnak').hasClass('itemCur')) {
    var pntr = $('.yumnak').hasClass('itemCur');
    pntr.next().addClass('itemCur');
    pntr.next().removeClass('item');
    pntr.removeClass('itemCur');
    pntr.addClass('item');
}
```

and the markup as

```
<ul>
  <li class="yumnak itemCur"><a href="#">one</a></li>
  <li class="yumnak item"><a href="#">two</a></li>
  <li class="yumnak item"><a href="#">three</a></li>
  <li class="yumnak item"><a href="#">four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here, won't my `pntr` not work?? It seems it's not working. How do I maintain a pointer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `$('.yumnak').hasClass('itemCur')` returns a boolean indicating whether it has the class.

You probably want to write `$('.yumnak.itemCur')` to select an element with both classes..

Answer (score 1):

hasClass just returns a boolean value. You want to select the element which you can do like this:

```
 var pntr = $('.yumnak.itemCur');
```

Answer (score 1):

What they all said. Currently `var pntr` is returning either true or false so your jquery chaining isn't actually attaching to any document node. It's trying to chain to either `true` or `false` which will fail.

you could set `var pntr = $(this)`, that should should reference the parent in the condition.

so

```
if($('.yumnak').hasClass('itemCur')) {
    var pntr = $(this);
    pntr.next().addClass('itemCur');
    pntr.next().removeClass('item');
    pntr.removeClass('itemCur');
    pntr.addClass('item');
}
```

Comment: note, using $(this) saves in DOM parsing resulting in faster jquery since it doesn't have to start from the beginning at every chain.

Answer (score 0):

`var pntr = $('.yumnak').hasClass('itemCur');` will return true or false depending if the element contains that class. To get the actual handle of the element use:

`var pntr = $('.yumnak');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasClass` function returns a boolean.

Actually you are calling the next() method on a boolean value.

Try this:

```
var pntr;

if ($('.yumnak').hasClass('itemCur')) {
    pntr = $('.yumnak');
} else {
    return; //or do other stuff
}
```